# How to use Green Hills Multi IDE to compile Linux application

Tags: linux, compiler-specific

Green Hills MULTI 6.xx currently support 2 proprietary OSs, INTEGRITY and VelOSity as well as ThreadX (let's not call it an OS). Has anyone tried to use their compiler and libraries to compile apps for Linux? I went through their user manual and the cc86 compiler offers flags -syslib and -os_dir, which are meant for working with embedded OSs. But documentations around this area is scared... any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you been able to get Green Hills to compile a Linux application? I am trying to do the same thing. GHS documentation shows that it can. In fact, their MULTI IDE manual even has a picture of showing that you can select INTEGRITY and VelOSity and Linux.

Comment: Hi Fred. No I haven't. Several of their docs indeed suggest the compiler can be used for Linux apps development. I've also been in touch with GHS Apps Engineers, but they said no (at least for x86 target, so dont' know about ARM). If you like to dig around further, this might shed more light http://wiki.osdev.org/OS_Specific_Toolchain